# Uniform approximation of continuous functions in Sobolev spaces by smooth functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $ \phi \in W^{k,p} (U)$  where $p \neq \infty$ and $U$ is a bounded $C^1$ open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose moreover that $\phi \in C(\bar{U})$. It is a standard fact(cf. Partial Differential Equations by Evans) that there exists a sequence $u_m \in C^\infty(\bar{U})$ such that $u_m \rightarrow \phi$ in $ W^{k,p} (U)$.

**Is it true that we can choose $u_m$ so that the convergence is also uniform(on $\bar{U}$)? Are there any references?**

Comment: For $kp > n$ it follows from Sobolev embedding that in fact *any* sequence converging in $W^{k,p}$ also converges in $C$.  I'd have to think about the case $k \leq \frac{n}{p}$.